# Explanation of relationship between pressure and poiling point of water

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, phase-transition

Explain how an increase in pressure elevates the boiling point of water, while reducing the pressure depresses the boiling point?

Comment: Note that asking a question with a command (*Explain [this] to me*) is considered a little rude.

Answer (score 3):

The boiling point of any substance may be defined as '**the temperature at which the pressure of its own vapors become equal to the external pressure**'. So for example in the case of water, at 100<sup>o</sup>C, the vapor pressure become equal to approx. 1 atm. Now if you increase the pressure further, you would need to heat the sample more such that the new pressure is balanced. Hence the boiling point is increased. The opposite happens for a decrease in the external pressure.